# How to make Django restart runserver on template change?

Tags: django, templates

When I make a modification in a python source file in my project, Django detects that and restart runserver itself. But when I modify a django template, I have to kill runserver and restart it again : how can I do to have runserver restart automatically on template change ?

Comment: [`RUNSERVER_PLUS_EXTRA_FILES = []` in an extension plugin](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/runserver_plus.html) is possibly an option, although I haven't tried this.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The file will by default be read from disk on every request, so there is no need to restart anything.

There is a caching template loader, but it is disabled by default. See [the documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#loader-types) for more info.

Comment: In settings, I forgot I have set the template caching. So I replace
('django.template.loaders.cached.Loader',('django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',)), by 'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader', and now no restart is needed : Many thanks

Comment: I'm not having this issue with regular templates (just the default settings are used), but I'm having this issue with some crispyforms overrides. (they only update on restart). I believe this is because crispyforms templates are loaded from within a template tag. Any ideas what is happening here?

Comment: it seems the reason that crispyforms templates require a restart is that they use the memoize() function to cache templates. There doesn't to be any way to turn it off in dev mode which can cause a lot of confusion. Looking through the Django source the only other place memoize() is used is in storing patterns which is why runserver requires a restart if you change urls.

Comment: Regarding crispyforms, I wonder if you could use *liveupdate* to tell the browser to update when your source files change.  Take a look at https://github.com/tjwalch/django-livereload-server.  I installed django-livereload-server and now the browser updates to reflect edits to javascript files loaded from tags in templates.

Answer (score 11):

Another solution is to make sure you have `debug` set to true inside of you `TEMPLATES` config in `settings.py`

```
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates/'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
            'debug': DEBUG,
        },
    },
]
```

When `debug` is False you  have to manually restart the server to see any changes made to templates (since they don't automatically trigger a restart)

Comment: Your answer saved me a lot of time，Although it says in the documentation that "it defaults to the value of the debugging setting." But I have to set it up by myself.

Answer (score 10):

Run `touch` against one of the Python source files.

Because `runserver` monitors .py files for changes, it does not restart for a change in the templates (.html). You can trigger this restart by virtually editing any of the .py files using the `touch` command, which refreshes its date modified and leaves all the other contents the same.

Comment: The OP already said that he edited a Python source file, so I don't see what would `touch` change.

Comment: @kermit666: No, he said he edited a template. Templates are not Python source files.

Comment: OK, you are right, my mistake. I'll retract the down-vote once it gets unlocked. Although the method still is a bit too hacky for my taste :) Ideally we'd have some nice integration between grunt-contrib-watch and Django's runserver.

Comment: Sorry, I can't undo my vote according to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21462/undoing-an-old-vote-cannot-be-recast-because-vote-is-too-old). If you can, please edit it (maybe with the contents of your comment) and I'll then fix my vote.

Comment: Django 1.11 on IIS, ran into this issue today and this is what solved it, thanks stranger. For anyone else searching for this issue, it was especially odd because it's only a problem when `DEBUG = False` in `settings.py`, and this is on a production IIS server, not running via `runserver`.

Comment: IMHO, this is actually a better answer than the 'accepted answer' by @knutin which is not _quite_ correct for all instances/configuration possibilities, while doing a `touch` to one of the `.py` files will certainly work well (testing on an old Django installation in FreeBSD). Then again, I've next-to-zero experience with Django, so I have no idea if _my_ comment is correct 

Answer (score 6):

To add to knutin's answer, the problem you are facing is exactly caused by FetchFromCacheMiddleware so all what you need to do is to disable it in the settings.py file as follows:

settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    #'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
    ...
)
```

Answer (score 4):

In newer Django versions:

The cached template loader is **enabled** by default, refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/api/#django.template.Engine :

> `loaders` is a list of template loader classes, specified as strings. Each Loader class knows how to import templates from a particular source. Optionally, a tuple can be used instead of a string. The first item in the tuple should be the Loader class name, subsequent items are passed to the Loader during initialization.
>
> It defaults to a list containing:
>
> - `'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader'`
> - `'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader'` if and only if `app_dirs` is `True`.
>
> **These loaders are then wrapped in [`django.template.loaders.cached.Loader`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.cached.Loader).**

and:

> Changed in Django 4.1:
> In older versions, the cached template loader was only enabled by default when `DEBUG` was `False`.

which means that **even if `DEBUG` is `True`, the cached template loader is still used**.

For reasons unknown to me, if `./manage.py runserver` is used then the files are **still read every time** regardless of `DEBUG` value;
while if `gunicorn mysite.wsgi:application` or `./manage.py runserver_plus` is used then the files are cached as expected.

Anyway, following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47448221/5267751) in order to *not* wrap the loaders in `cached.Loader` always works.
(you need to add the option to [`TEMPLATES.OPTIONS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#std-setting-TEMPLATES-OPTIONS),
which is passed to [`template.Engine`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/api/#django.template.Engine) -- remember to remove `app_dirs` if any)

---

Another alternative is to add to `settings.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django_extensions',
```

then run for example

```
./manage.py runserver_plus  --extra-file polls/templates/polls/index.html
```

See https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/runserver_plus.html for documentation.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to restart the server to reload the template changes.

In production you may do this:
In settings.py, for the TEMPLATES config
- Remove the APP_DIRS setting
- Instead, add this setting to OPTIONS:

```
'loaders': [
  'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
  'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
],
```

Why this works:
The DEBUG setting is True by default (in development mode). In this mode Django does not cache templates. But in production mode (i.e. DEBUG = False) Django enables template caching. Hence a server restart is needed to reload the edited/touched template.

Note:
Be mindful of the fact that - by disabling template caching, on your production machine, you will add an overhead for every request that goes through.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, however my templates required a django manager script to run in order to update them.  There is no simple way to make django watch other file types, but here is a work around I use.

This is a standalone script I now use to run the dev server:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time, subprocess, sys, os, re
from threading import Thread

run = True

def monitor():
  while run:
    os.system("./manage.py update_templates")
    os.system("touch website/urls.py")
    os.system("inotifywait -e modify,create,delete website/templates/*.html")

t = Thread(target=monitor)
t.start()
time.sleep(0.5)

args = ''
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
  for i in range( 1, len(sys.argv)):
    args += sys.argv[i] +' '
print("./manage.py runserver %s" % args)
os.system("./manage.py runserver %s" % args)
run = False
t.join()
```

This script works under the following assumptions:

1. Using python3
2. This script is placed along side manager.py
3. manager.py is runnable
4. The web app is called website
5. The website has a file called website/urls.py
6. You're using GNU/Linux, which supports inotify

Answer (score 0):

The file will be read from disk without the need to restart runserver, just make sure you disable all caching.

**Disable the Cached template loader**

THe cached template loader is not enabled by default but you might have enabled this in you production settings. Make sure the cached template loader is not enabled your development settings. [Django docs on the cached template loader](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.cached.Loader)

**Use the dummy caching framework**

When you are using the django caching framework this can cause the templates not to reload. The default framework Django uses is local-memory caching meaning you'll have to explicitly setup dummy caching to disable the caching framework. [Django docs on dummy caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/cache/#dummy-caching-for-development)