# Django Not Reflecting Updates to Javascript Files?

Tags: python, django

I have javascript files in my `static` folder. Django finds and loads them perfectly fine, so I don't think there is anything wrong with my configuration of the `static` options. However, sometimes when I make a change to a `.js` file and save it, the Django template that uses it does NOT reflect those changes -- inspecting the javascript with the browser reveals the javascript BEFORE the last save. Restarting the server does nothing, though restarting my computer has sometimes solved the issue. I do not have any code that explicitly deals with caching. Has anyone ever experienced anything like this?

Comment: I experienced that one, I just refresh it many times so that my new updates for js will make an update on the system.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I believe your browser is caching your js

you could power refresh your browser, or clear browser cache?

on chrome control+f5  or shift + f5

i *believe* on firefox it is control + shift + r

Answer (score 17):

Since you are editing JavaScript files and watching for the changes in the browser I assume you are actively developing your Django app and probably using Django's development runserver.  There is a better solution than clearing the browser cache and refreshing.  If you run a watcher utility that supports the livereload protocol then your browser will automatically refresh whenever you change *any* static file.

The [`django-livereload-server`](https://pypi.org/project/django-livereload-server/) Python package provides a spiffy solution.  Install it:

```
$ pip install django-livereload-server
```

Add `'livereload.middleware.LiveReloadScript'` to `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` in settings.py.

Then run

```
$ ./manage.py livereload
```

before starting the runserver.

More documentation can be found at [the django-livereload-server github site](http://github.com/tjwalch/django-livereload-server)

Comment: See the README on GitHub for instructions updated for Django >1.10

Answer (score 1):

For me, opening ***Incognito Mode*** in Chrome let the browser show the recent changes in my `.js` static files.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who is using Firefox:
If you don't want to clean your browser cache or it doesn't solve your issue, you can try doing a hard refresh (hold Shift and press the refresh button).