# CSRF 403 in default Django login

Tags: django

I'm fairly new to Django. Here's what I need insight on:

After updating from Django 3 to 4:

On the local dev server, no issue.

On production: CSRF 403 error on login.

There's a cookie loaded on the login page containing

```
csrftoken: pAFeeUI8YFXZ2PKRYxOTX1qz4Xgto42WVNi7FFvBlZDqcFLwQ2rdQvVeZBHFSpLW
```

(Local and Session storage are empty)

In the FORM element:

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="Vz4FiujD4qkLpxCwWNJU0HCWs4u0Qf4RrMHyJf66rK0cznDbOimeTb7BnIVckANR">
```

Notice they *don't match*.

I tried manually deleting the cookie and also running `./migrate.py clearsessions`.

The first time, yesterday, it seemed that the error did not occur in an Incognito Window, but today it persists even in an incognito window, as well as a different browser.

#### One additional piece of information

[allauth](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) had been previously installed, but was causing infinite redirect loop on login, so removed. The login page url is `/login/?next=/`.

Thanks much.

Comment: Are you using any sort of caching?

Comment: I'm not sure. Locally `./migrate.py` includes a `cache_clear` method, but not on the production server. It's running in a Docker container via gunicorn. Can you recommend where I would look?

Comment: Maybe nginx is caching...

Comment: Do you have something like `@cache_page` decorators in your code?

Comment: I don't. Not finding the word `cache` anywhere in the codebase.

Comment: Also I believe I have disabled nginx caching. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55572756/2223106

Comment: If you have any downstream caches like you mention NGINX, etc. make sure they add a `Vary: Cookie` header on any page having a form (Otherwise they'll cache the page having other users CSRF token)

Comment: Looking into that now.

Comment: Issue ended up being that  needed to add `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ["https://yourdomain.com", "https://www.yourdomain.com"]` Do you want to write up an answer that includes that?

Answer (score 0):

You should add `{% csrf_token %}`:

```
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="Vz4FiujD4qkLpxCwWNJU0HCWs4u0Qf4RrMHyJf66rK0cznDbOimeTb7BnIVckANR">
```

Answer (score 0):

At least in Django 4.0, you can–and possibly must–specify CSRF trusted origins in your `settings.py` file:

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ["https://yourdomain.com", "https://www.yourdomain.com"]
```

Note `www` *and* `non-www` as well as no trailing `/`.

At any rate, it solved the issue for me.

See [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/csrf/).